# in IE8,span display:none doesn't work in other's computer but not mine

Tags: html

```
<span id='a' style='display:none;'>
<input type=button value='a'>
</span>
<span id='b' style='display:none;'>
<input type=button value='b'>
</span>
```

these codes work correct on my computer ,but not the others.
It seems like span does not work.

Comment: No, **IE 8** doesn't work.  Or you're not accommodating for some weird edge case that it's coming up with.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? IE8 handles it the same as any other browser; displays nothing, as both spans are hidden. See http://jsfiddle.net/uMHK2/show/ in IE8.

Comment: We solve it.it is the Compatibility of IE8.span doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and fixed it by replacing the span with a DIV. IE doesn't render  span with the 'display:none' style properly, while Firefox and Chrome don't have this issue.